# Interpolation in I18n array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, interpolation, rails-i18n

I'm using arrays in a locale file to be able to generate blocks of text in various output methods (ActionMailer templates, Prawn documents, HAML templates) that are locale-specific. It works perfectly, but sometimes I want to pass variables into these I18n calls. However, this doesn't work.

Say my locale file looks like this:

```
en:
  my_array:
    - "Line 1"
    - "Line 2"
    - "Line 3 has a %{variable}"
    - "Line 4"
```

I want the output of `I18n.t('my_array', :variable => 'variable named variable')` to be as follows:

```
["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3 has a variable named variable", "Line 4"]
```

However, the output is:

```
["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3 has a %{variable}", "Line 4"]
```

Will I have to do the interpolation myself after retrieving the array? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: try this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: I could be missing something, but please point out where this is documented in that guide. I know the ROR guides pretty well.

Comment: Plx check this para:3.2 Passing variables to translations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the library

Answer (score 5):

I think such thing is not supported natively in i18n gem, but it's doable using some meta-programming magic.

In an initializer (say, `config/initializers/i18n.rb`) add the following

```
I18n.backend.instance_eval do
  def interpolate(locale, string, values = {})
    if string.is_a?(::Array) && !values.empty?
      string.map { |el| super(locale, el, values) }
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Git issue and PR to I18n gem created. Credits for you.
Follow here: https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/issues/281

Comment: I created an issue back then and was told that this is not something they'd like to see in I18n. So I didn't pursue, but your solution looks great. However, I remember I18n having trouble with keys that weren't included in the translation string, which is why I built my own interpolation helper (which was trivial).