# Stubbing .sample in Ruby - Rails project using Il8n gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, internationalization

I am working on a description generator feature that will look at an objects attributes and populate a description by pulling strings from various locales (in multiple languages) that are already setup.

I have the following code

```
module Rooms
  class DescriptionGenerator
  attr_reader :room, :locale

  def initialize(room, locale="en")
    @room = room
    @locale = locale
  end

  private

  def t(key, options={})
    I18n.t("rooms.description_generator.#{key}", options.merge({ locale: locale }))
  end

  def wifi
    t("wifi", room_type: room.room_type.type).values.sample if room.wifi
  end
```

I then have the following test:

```
describe "#wifi" do
  let!(:room_with_wifi) { create(:room, :visible, wifi: true) }
  let!(:room) { create(:room) }

  #This one is failing
  it "returns wifi sentence if room has wifi" do
    sentence = I18n.t('rooms.description_generator.wifi', room_type: room_with_wifi.room_type.type).values.sample
    expect(Rooms::DescriptionGenerator.new(room_with_wifi,"en").send(:wifi)).to eq (sentence)
  end

  it "returns nil if room does not have wifi" do
    expect(Rooms::DescriptionGenerator.new(room,"en").send(:wifi)).to eq nil
  end
end
```

My question is "What is the best way to test this given the use of sample?"

My original solution (which I am pretty sure is not recommended) was to add:

```
class DescriptionGenerator
  def sample(arr)
    if Rails.env.test?
      arr.values.first
    else
      arr.sample.values
    end
  end
end
```

This 'enforced' that RSpec would take the first option from my locales set out like this:

```
three_positive_reviews:
  a: "This is not so great"
  b: "This %{string_for_interpolation} is great."
  c: "This is bad"
```

This was all passing until I added a string to be interpolated into the first (a) that was being used in the test and realised that in i18n gem does not support interpolation within an array ([Interpolation in I18n array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574900/interpolation-in-i18n-array/25484080#25484080)).

So I refactored to:

```
def t(key, options={})
  value = I18n.t("rooms.description_generator.#{key}")
  key = "#{key}.#{sample(value.keys)}" if value.is_a?(Hash)
  I18n.t("rooms.description_generator.#{key}", options.merge({ locale: locale }))
end

def sample(keys)
  if Rails.env.test?
    keys.first
  else
    keys.sample
  end
end
```

This now passes my test suite - however having looked at this in some detail wanted to ask for more optimal solutions & also how I more appropriately test (perhaps by stubbing sample??) without the line

```
if Rails.env.test?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following (I didn't run the code, thought):

```
let(:room) { create(:room) }
let(:locale) { 'en' }
let(:generator) { Rooms::DescriptionGenerator.new(room, locale) } 

describe '#wifi' do
  let(:wifi_sentences) do
    I18n.t('rooms.description_generator.wifi', locale: locale)).values
  end

  context 'when the room has wifi' do
    it 'returns wifi sentence' do
      expect(generator.send(:wifi)).to be_in(wifi_sentences)
    end
  end

  context 'when the room has no wifi' do
    before do
      allow(room).to receive(:wifi).and_return(false) # or nil, don't know
    end

    it 'returns nil' do
      expect(generator.send(:wifi)).to be(nil)
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Victor for your answer - extremely helpful to refactor my tests. I wanted to post up my final solution which takes your advice into account with a few tweaks in case it's useful for others.

```
let(:room) { create(:room) }
let(:locale) { 'en' }
let(:generator) { Rooms::DescriptionGenerator.new(room, locale) }

describe "#laundry" do
  it "returns wifi sentence if room has wifi" do
    sentence = "This apartment is equipped with laundry facilities."
    room.laundry = true
    expect(generator.send(:laundry)).to eq(sentence)
  end

  it "returns nil if room is not have laundry" do
    expect(generator.send(:laundry)).to eq nil
  end
end
```

This works for a simple one option locale:

```
  laundry: "This %{room_type} is equipped with laundry facilities."
```

However due to the fact that Rails i18n cannot interpolate strings within an array (i.e. when there are multiple key-value pairs offered up) I stubbed sample.

```
context "translations with multiple options that require interpolation" do
  before do
    allow(generator).to receive(:sample) { |keys| keys.first }
  end

  describe "#three_positive_reviews" do

   context 'when the room has 3 positive reviews' do
     before do
       3.times do
         create(:feedback, :non_external, :positive, room: room)
       end
     end

    it "returns three_positive_reviews sentence" do
      sentence = "This apartment is highly reviewed"
      expect(generator.send(:three_positive_reviews)).to eq(sentence)
    end
  end

  context 'when the room does not have 3 positive reviews' do
    it "returns nil" do
      expect(generator.send(:three_positive_reviews)).to eq nil
    end
  end
```

and was then able to recfactor my sample method in my code to:

```
def sample(keys)
  keys.sample
end
```

This seems like a cleaner solution to me than my original posted in the question.